# Is it possible to map all Gitlab specific project's related remote to local directory via Sourcetree/Fork?

Tags: git, gitlab, repository, atlassian-sourcetree

currently I use GitLab (not enterprise) in my company. Logging, I'm able to see under a specific remote directory all projects and related repos.
Fine.
But as far as I understood, when I have to checkout a repo I have to go to the single repo of the single project map it locally and then I can browse it and play with it.
There is the scan functionality but it works only on local directory.
So imagine we have 100 repos, under 10 projects, I have to do manually that operation 100 times.
And if a new repo is born I can't there's no way I can spot that, I still have to map it manually.

Am I mistaken and/or is there any kind of workaround to prevent all this manual stuff?
Thx guys

Comment: By "project", do you mean Giltab's "group"?

Comment: No I mean project.
At the moment I am in one group. It would be wonderful to map all groups projects' repos (but dunno whether it's feasible).
Under this one group, there are many subgroups and projects (more than 60).
Each subgroup contains 1 or n projects and related repository.
Is there a way to avoid local repo map to remote specific repo? Whatever it is...

Answer (score 0):

If you need any kind of automation for a large set of projects, you can develop a script using the official [GitLab CLI glab](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/integration/glab/)

For instance, [`glab repo --list --member`](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/cli/-/blob/main/docs/source/repo/list.md) would list all projects which you are a member.
[`glab api`](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/cli/-/tree/main/docs/source/api) allows for any other API call which might not yet be implemented in a glab command.

Comment: Ok so there are no UI commands in tools like the clients I mentioned (Sourcetree, Flow or whatever else)?

Comment: @DioBrando No direct UI integration, but Sourcetree allows you to define a [custom action](https://yuchen52.medium.com/source-tree-custom-actions-e4c0fe190217) from which you can call your `glab` script.